# How to model a markov chain that randomly switches between two transition matrices?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-matrices, transition-matrix

Let's say I have a discrete time, time-homogeneous Markov chain $X = \{X_{1}, \dots , X_{n}\}$ with state space $S= \{1,2,3\}$ and a transition matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} 
.4 & .3 & .3\\
.3 & .5 & .2\\
.8 & .1 & .1
\end{bmatrix}

However, I want to model the process in the following way: Lets say we are currently visiting some state at $X_{10}$. Before we go to the next state at $X_{11}$, there is a small probability $p$ that it will first break out of this transition matrix and follow a new transition matrix:

\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & .5 & .5\\
.5 & 0 & .5\\
.5 & .5 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

Then, once the current state is $X_{11}$, we return to the original transition matrix but again before we go to $X_{12}$ there is again the small probability $p$ of first breaking out to the second matrix, and so on and so on endlessly.

Is there a way to model this behavior mathematically? Practically, while I can program this behavior, I cannot use n-step transition matrices because they are meaningless. The n-step transition of the first matrix alone wouldn't account for the ability of the process to break out and switch chains.

My guess is that I have to somehow weight the first matrix using the second which I have no idea how to do, but the probability $p$ of breaking out is a nuisance. Also, if it is of any concern, the actual matrix I am trying to model is size 256 x 256, so ultimately the solution needs to be able to be run by a computer.

Comment: You could double your state space, with $k$ states for chain 1, and $k$ for chain 2, so that $(i,1)\to (j,1)$ with prob $(1-p)P_{i,j}$ and $(i,1)\to(j,2)$ with prob $p P_{i,j}$ and so on.  Formally your transition matrix is $2k\times 2k$ but you explicitly store only $2$ $k\times k$ transition matrices...

Comment: @kimchilover If I'm reading the fine print of the original post correctly --  "once the current state is $X_{11}$, we return to the original transition matrix" -- then I think we don't even have to work that hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done reasonably simply. All you have to do is to carefully consider the *true* transition probabilities.

Consider, for instance, the probability of going from state 1 to state 2 in a single step. If the "original" matrix is used, then this probability is $0.3$. If the switch happens, then this probability is $0.5$. Regard this as a holistic process: the probability of transitioning from state 1 to state 2 is therefore 
\begin{align*} &P(1 \rightarrow 2 \mid \text{no switch}) \cdot P(\text{no switch}) + P(1 \rightarrow 2 \mid \text{switch}) \cdot P(\text{switch}) \\
&\qquad =  0.3(1-p) + 0.5 p.
\end{align*}
 Similar comments apply when transitioning between *any* two states, so it shouldn't be hard to convince yourself that the transition matrix should be $(1-p)A + pB$, where $A$ is the "default" transition matrix and $B$ is the second transition matrix. From here, you have a good old-fashioned Markov chain with a new transition matrix.